# Close all puppeteer browsers

Tags: puppeteer

Is it possible to close all running puppeteer browsers using some block of code?
I have opened more browsers using for loop and I want to stop them before exiting the process using `process.exit()`.

I would like to to clear temporary files of the browsers (cached and others), I am starting browsers using
`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-features=site-per-process',  '--proxy-server=proxy_url'] });`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can the method `close()`, see https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v12.0.1&show=api-browserclose

Single browser:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-features=site-per-process',  '--proxy-server=proxy_url'] });


// ... DO STUFF ...


await browser.close();
```

Multiple browsers:

```js
const browserOptions = { headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-features=site-per-process',  '--proxy-server=proxy_url'] };

const maxBrowsers = 3;
const allBrowsers = [];

for(let i = 0; i < maxBrowsers; ++i) {
    const aBrowser = await puppeteer.launch(browserOptions);
    allBrowsers.push(aBrowser);
}


// ... DO STUFF ...


// close browsers one by one
for(let aBrowser of allBrowsers) {
    await aBrowser.close();
}

// or close browsers all at once
// await Promise.all(
//     allBrowsers.map(aBrowser => aBrowser.close())
// );
```